# Highcharts halo in inside how?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

Is it possible to place inside on hover, series.pie.states.hover.halo?
https://codepen.io/thomas_rz/pen/vXyoaK `code here`
https://prnt.sc/26x29mu `image code here`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative value for `size` in `halo` options, for example:

```
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    innerSize: '90%',
    states: {
      hover: {
        halo: {
          size: -30
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nL02o4ef/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.states.hover.halo.size

Comment: Thanks to. I already tried with a minus value, but it's a very small number and it didn't work. Thanks for your help everything works)